# Error when trying to run command 'flutter run'

Tags: android, windows, flutter, gradle

I was trying to run command 'flutter run' Its giving me errors. There are no issues with flutter doctor. I don't know where the error is from, I tried to run this flutter clean, flutter pub cache repair, flutter run. Still the same error.

````
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:                   
! intl 0.17.0
Running "flutter pub get" in cretello_rentors_plus_1...            34.3s
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you notice graphics
artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dynamic_theme-1.0.1/lib/dynamic_theme.dart:25:46: Error: Method not found: 'TypeMatcher'.
    return context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<DynamicThemeState>());
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dynamic_theme-1.0.1/lib/dynamic_theme.dart:25:20: Error: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorStateOfType'.
    return context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<DynamicThemeState>());  
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutterSDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        44.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```
````

Answer (score 1):

This issues is due to your flutter versions. If you are copying others code, make sure to first run.

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`

If this does not work make sure you use the correct versions of the flutter sdk.

Answer (score 0):

try one of this solutions
———
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/issues/140